# copy constructor in c++ with different arguments

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor

Why this code is calling the copy constructor when the object passed is not of type Line and there is no equal to operator/explicit calling. Is there a difference between Line A and Line A().
I read from many online tutorials that it should be of Line type.I am a newbie to C++.Please help

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
    ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete ptr;
}
int Line::getLength( void )
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( )
{
   Line line(10);

   display(line);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: _" Is there a difference between `Line A;` and `Line A();`?"_ [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 10):

It's because your `display` method accepts its argument *by value* - as a result a copy is made when you pass the argument. To avoid the copy, declare the parameter to be a *reference* to a `Line` instead, by adding an ampersand, `&`:

```
void display(Line& obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}
```

If you want to make sure that the `display` method doesn't modify your `Line`, also consider making it a `const` reference:

```
void display(const Line& obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}
```

You'd then also need to declare your `Line::getLength()` method to be a `const` member function, since otherwise the compiler won't allow you to invoke it on a `const` object:

```
int getLength( void ) const;
```

Answer (score 2):

*Generally* a copy constructor would be called in following cases:

1. When an object of the class is returned by value.
2. When an object of the class is passed (to a function) by value as an argument. **(*this is your case*)**
3. When an object is constructed based on another object of the same class. e.g. A(obj)
4. When compiler generates a temporary object.